# Hello all, I have a question regarding the STM32F411CEU6 USART2

Tags: stm32f4

I had already written a set of serial-related functions (interrupt on receive for USART2) that worked fine on the STM32F401CCU6 - using the CUBEMX to set up the peripherals.

All good, until I decided to port this code to the STM32F411CEU6 - again using the CUBEMX as the kick-off for the project.

I set up the clock configuration to 100Mhz for the '411 (as I had done for the '401 (84Mhz) and '407 in another project (168Mhz)). Everything else worked fine (LCD interface, 74HC595 on SPI etc).

I did find that the system would not receive anything from USART2.

Setting a break-point in the RX interrupt, it became apparent that the RX was getting junk.

Looked to me like a baud-rate problem.

To prove this, I transmitted a series of bytes from the main while() loop to see what the bit times there were at the TX pin. For 115200, that ought to be about 8.6 microseconds.
e.g.
while(1)
{
HAL_Delay(1);
console_puts_uart2("AAAAAAAA");
}

From what I could see on my CRO, the bit times were more like 12.5 us, equating to ~80000 baud.

So, roughly 115200 x 0.7.

I then ran an experiment.

Where the baud rate is set into the huart2 structure, I multiplied '115200' by '1.428571' (1.0 divided by 0.7), giving a notional baud-rate of "164505".

```
 /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 164505;  //115200; -- multiply 115200 by 1.428571
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
   Error_Handler();
  }
 /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */
```

Now the actual baud rate (measured) is 115200 and everything works as normal - All fixed!!!

**My question is:** Has anybody seen this before? Are there any 'errata' to look at for the STM32F411?
I cant find anything like this in my google searches. Very frustrating to fix this one. :(

I was expecting the CUBEMX baud-rate variable to set the right divisors for the APB1 bus. (50Mhz) to give 115200 baud.

In the end, I had to fudge the baud-rate value in the initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It has to do with the fact I had used the HSI input to the clock, not the HSE at the PPL source MUX. This threw the calculations out the window. Now, 25mhz (external clock HSE) divided by 25, Multiplied by 200 (PLL), gave a system clock of 100Mhz (APB1 Clock of 50Mhz) as before, but now the standard calculations as per CubeMX work as expected. Steve

Comment: Can you choose your own answer as an answer then? To close the question?